# Java generics constraint for same type

Tags: java, sql, generics, jdbc, constraints

I got the following problem. My generic class CursorPointer delivers a cursor to a SQL database where it provides several methods to extract the values for the current cursor position. Now I would like to provide an interface that is able to requery a cursor of the same type.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
public abstract class CursorPointer<TElement> {

    public static interface ICursorQuery<TElement> {
        public CursorPointer<TElement> query();
    }

    private final ICursorQuery<TElement> reQueryHandler;
    private final Cursor cursor;

    public CursorPointer(Cursor cursor, ICursorQuery<TElement> reQueryHandler) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.reQueryHandler = reQueryHandler;
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return cursor;
    }

    public CursorPointer<TElement> reQuery() {

        try {
            return reQueryHandler == null ? null : reQueryHandler.query();
        } finally {
            this.close();
        }
    }

    public TElement get(int position) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        return get();
    }

    public TElement get() {
        return get(cursor);
    }

    protected abstract TElement get(Cursor cursor);
}
```

An implementation of that cursor will result in something like this:

```
public class RouteCursor extends CursorPointer<RouteElement> {

    @Override
    public CursorPointer<RouteElement> reQuery() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.reQuery();
    }
}
```

So the return type of the reQuery-method is generic, too. But I actually want a generic constrain on the CursorPointer class so that the return type of reQuery MUST be RouteCursor again.

But how to define that constraint?

Comment: A parent class/interface should not return a child class/interface.

Comment: How about defining a second generic parameter on the `CursorPointer` class of `<? extends CursorPointer>`?  It's a bit yucky.

Comment: Or better yet, have the `reQuery()` function return `<? extends CursorPointer<RouteElement>>`  That should do it, no?

Comment: When I override a method that has the constraint <? extends ...> and change its return type to the real one (lets say "RouteCursor") than I get a warning and I need to supress that warning then.

Comment: @TrippKinetics - I was going to post up an answer to that effect, but I would feel like I was cheating if I posted it now. Post up your own answer with some details and a little code and I'll upvote it. :)

Comment: @Rudi that's no cheating. Just post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

In CursorPointer:

```
public <U extends CursorPointer<TElement>> U reQuery() {

    try {
        return (U) reQueryHandler == null ? null : reQueryHandler.query();
    } finally {
        this.close();
    }
}
```

In RouteCursor:

```
public RouteCursor reQuery() {
    return super.reQuery();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `ICursorQuery#query` returns `CursorPointer<TElement>`. Even if changing this design, won't work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - That's not true. `query()` has a return type of an abstract class, and you can't create an object of that class. As such whatever `query()` returns **will** match the criteria for `U`, or be null.

Comment: @Rudi yes, but then which methods you'll be able to call from the returned object?

Comment: Then you still need to add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to the overridden method.